# Sticky footer not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, mobile, layout

I would like to create a sticky / floating bottom footer for my calorie calculator, thing is, it works great on desktop, but not on mobile. Any ideas what might be the issue?

HTML:

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="summary">
        <table id="nodecor">
            <tr>
                <th>Total Calories: </th>
                <th>Carbs: </th>
                <th>Fat: </th>
                <th>Protein:</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bigtext"><span id="total">0</span> G</td>
                <td class="bigtext"><span id="totalCarbs">0</span> G</td>
                <td class="bigtext"><span id="totalFats">0</span> G</td>
                <td class="bigtext"><span id="totalProteins">0</span> G</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS:

```
    .footer {

  padding: 10px;
  height:15%;
  position: fixed;
  width:100%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Here's the [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/Pbalazs89/full/aYabdO) as it might be easier to visualize.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: correct your code alignment.also there is some mistake in your code like table heading ends with </div> .

Comment: Your codepen works ok on my phone (android)

Comment: Thanks, I'm spotting it only on iOS

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the issue you are having seems to be your wrong html code format. Try this format for your html code you have mentioned in your question.

```
<footer class="footer">
    <div class="summary">
        <table id="nodecor">
            <tr>
                <th>Total Calories: </th>
                <th>Carbs: </th>
                <th>Fat: </th>
                <th>Protein: </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="bigtext"><span id="total">0</span> G</td>
                <td class="bigtext"><span id="totalCarbs">0</span> G</td>
                <td class="bigtext"><span id="totalFats">0</span> G</td>
                <td class="bigtext"><span id="totalProteins">0</span> G</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Hi there, tried it, still have the same issue on iOS. Here's the updated pen: https://codepen.io/Pbalazs89/full/MVqzZg